# How can i serialize multiple forms with multiples id's using js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to serialize forms passing multiple id's by reference.
I have something like this.

```
<code>
    keys = ['someref1','someref2',....,'someref99];
    data_serializes = $("#data-"+keys.join(",#data")).serialize();
</code>
```

You can see that my form id start with "data-" and the complement has to be the key in my array.
But it's not working.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: It should works in my view if you also think you're missing a dash `-` while you joining the ID `$("#data-"+keys.join(",#data-"))`

Comment: you are right, i was missing a dash in my function. It's already working, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$.each` and serialize every form, interpolating the value with a jQuery selector:

```js
$('#serialize').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let ids = ['first', 'second']
  $.each(ids, function(index, value) {
    console.log($(`#${value}`).serialize())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="first">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<form id="second">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<a href="#" id="serialize">Serialize</a>
```

Or if you want to get the "ids" dinamycally and then iterate over every element and to serialize you can:

```js
$('#serialize').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $.each($('*[id^="data-"]'), function(e) {
    console.log( $(`#${$(this).attr('id')}`).serialize() )
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="data-first">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<form id="data-second">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<a href="#" id="serialize">Serialize</a>
```

Comment: I've got it, but doing in that way i will have to concatenate the value of each form in a variable, to get my final value.